# Kotlin - not able to find kotin equivalent of java.util.function.Function<T, R>

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert one of the java function which takes `java.util.function.Function<T, R>` to Kotlin using **IDEA 2019.3 Kotlin multiplatform** library.

But t I could not find a way to do an  equivalent function in kotlin.  I can see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt)  that  there is  Function1 to do a java interoperability but I am not able to do any import from import kotlin.jvm.functions.*

I am trying Kotlin for the first time. Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong.

Update- Please see my java code

import java.util.function.Function;

```
public class A {
    Function<String, String> function;

    public A(Function<String, String> function) {
        super();
        this.function = function;
    }

public String convert(String input) {
    return function.apply(input);

}
}
```

Comment: Please share code, so that we can understand your problem better

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to use a Java library in your Kotlin project, or duplicate functionality?

Comment: I was trying to duplicate the functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear about your question, but assuming you are trying to duplicate functionality from Java:

In Kotlin, you do not use Function interfaces directly because functions are first-class. The Function1, Function2, etc. classes are only used to make functions available to Java code and the JVM.

If you want to create the equivalent of a Java `Function<T, R>`, you would define a function using either Kotlin's `fun` or lambda syntax.

```
fun getStringLength(x: String): Int {
    return x.length
}

//...
val functionReference = ::getStringLength
// Java code will treat this as a Function1<String, Int>
```

or

```
val function = fun (x: String): Int {
    return x.length
}
// Java code will treat this as a Function1<String, Int>
```

or

```
val functionReference = { x: String -> x.length }
// Java code will treat this as a Function1<String, Int>
```

To declare that a function takes a function as a parameter, you use `(input) -> output` syntax as the variable type:

```
fun <T, R> doSomething(functionalReference: (T) -> R) {
    //
}
```

You can call a function using its referenced name:

```
fun <T, R> doSomething(input: T, functionalReference: (T) -> R): R {
    return functionalReference(input)
}
```

Comment: In the end I did something on this line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to convert a Java function that accepts a Function to an equivalent Kotlin function.

Example:

**Java**

```
public class JavaFunctions {
   public static <T,R> void runAFunction(Function<T, R> userFunction){
      userFunction.apply(null);
   }
}
```

**Kotlin** (These two functions are equivalent)

```
class KotlinFunctions{
   companion object{
      @JvmStatic
      fun <T,R> runAFunction(userFunction:(T?) -> R?){
         userFunction.invoke(null);
      }

      @JvmStatic
      fun <T,R> runAFunction2(userFunction: Function1<T?, R?> ){
         userFunction.invoke(null);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used something as @Tenfour04